# ansible handler with multiple tasks

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible, core 2.11.4, but I had issues with running multiple handlers (to remove some installer files).
It looks that second step is not processed and the files are not removed.
I also tried with a `block`, but it looks like this does not work with handlers.

```yaml
---
# handlers file for removal
- name: Remove installer
  find:
    paths: /etc/wild_card/example
    paths: /tmp/
    patterns: "Installer*"
    use_regex: true
  register: wildcard_files_to_delete
  notify: Remove installer step 2

- name: Remove installer step 2
  file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ wildcard_files_to_delete.files }}"
```

Debug:

```
RUNNING HANDLER [ : Remove  installer] ****************************
"path": "/tmp/Installer.tgz", }
META: ran handlers
META: role_complete for host
META: ran handlers
```

Comment: It is absoultely not clear from the above if the second task is correctly declared in a hanldler section or not. Please provide a correct [mre].

Comment: yes, all was part of handlers, req. updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to trigger multiple handlers, use the `listen` keyword on the handlers and notify that rather than individual handler names. For example:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - command: /bin/true
      notify: my_notification_name

  handlers:
    - name: handler 1
      listen: my_notification_name
      debug:
        msg: this is handler 1

    - name: handler 2
      listen: my_notification_name
      debug:
        msg: this is handler 2
```

Which behaves like this when run:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************

TASK [command] ****************************************************
changed: [localhost]

RUNNING HANDLER [handler 1] ***************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "this is handler 1"
}

RUNNING HANDLER [handler 2] ***************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "this is handler 2"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```